# docker でホストへ bind した port が、 tcp6 に bind されているのに tcp4 で接続できている理由がわからない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tcp

ubuntu 14.04 上に、 docker をインストールしています。

この上で、コンテナ (elasticsearch) を、適切に host へマッピングしながらデーモン実行して(補足参照)、`netstat -lnp`を実行したところ、どうも tcp6 に対してのみ port が bind されているように見えます。

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ netstat -lnp | egrep '(9200|9300)'
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

しかし、この状態でも、 tcp4 での接続は、正しく動作している様子でした。

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl -4 127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "name" : "Rahne Sinclair",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.2.0",
    "build_hash" : "8ff36d139e16f8720f2947ef62c8167a888992fe",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-01-27T13:32:39Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

自分の理解ですと、 tcp6 と tcp4 はプロトコルが別なので、 tcp6 で特定の port へ bind していたとしても、tcp4 のプロトコルでは、接続ができないのではないかと思っているのですが、上記の通り、今手元の環境では、そうではない動作をしています。

質問:

- どうして、 tcp6 でしか bind していないように見えるのに、 tcp4 でアクセスできているのでしょうか。

---

補足:

コンテナの実行に利用したコマンドは、次の通りでした。

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elasticsearch
```

Comment: `curl -4 127.0.0.1:9200`としても結果は同じですか？

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi 変わらないですね、編集します。

Comment: [Docker Issue#2174](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2174)でしょう。bharrisau commented on Jun 4, 2014で挙動が説明されています。僕自身確かめたわけではないのでご参考まで。[本家の回答](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957143/make-docker-use-ipv4-for-port-binding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OSの仕様上、デフォルトではIPv6のソケットはIPv4の接続も受け付けることができます。
IPv4のアドレスは自動的にIPv6の「IPv4射影アドレス」に変換されます。

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html

> ```
>    IPv4 and IPv6 share the local port space.  When you get an IPv4
>    connection or packet to a IPv6 socket, its source address will be
>    mapped to v6 and it will be mapped to v6.
> ```

Comment: なるほど。Docker固有の問題ではなくLinuxの挙動なわけですね。